# Problems with using two Umbraco Media pickers

Tags: umbraco

When I added a Media Picker on a Document Type in Umbraco I was able to select an item from the media library but when I added another Media Picker to the same Document Type none of them worked?

I am using Umbraco 4.0.2.1

BR, Larre

Comment: You may be better asking this on the umbraco forum at http://forum.umbraco.org/

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, can you be more specific about what doesn't work?

Comment: I tried to replicate the error on another server but there it worked so I guess there is something wrong with my installation. Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the "error" if I had a space in the name of the field f.ex. "top image" I could only use one Media Picker, when I changed the name to "topimage" everything worked as a charm. I also found similar problems with other fields and solved them the same way.